# Django ignores model field

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-migrations

So, I came across this when I was working on a project.

I had mistakenly placed a "," after a field in one of my models and Django did all the migrations while ignoring that particular field. It took me a while to realize that a little "," after the field is responsible for my field not being reflected in the database.

However, I understand that there shouldn't be a coma but I was kind of expecting Django to give me an error or at least a warning.

Something like maybe:
"Invalid syntax in models.py near FieldName"

**EDIT:**
"one or more model fields are stored as tuple/s are you sure you want to do so?"

But it ignores that particular field and keeps on migrating. My question is why does Django let that happen? Is this the expected behaviour and shouldn't Django notify for such things? or why this is being passed silently.

Here is an example to have a look at.

```
class person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=10),
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Now, if you create migrations and apply them Django will simply ignore the surname field here and apply the migrations without any errors, why is it so?

Comment: Remove the comma (`,`) at the end. By using a trailing comma, you wrap the field in a 1-tuple.

Comment: I know the solution, but can you tell me what exactly "you wrap the field in a 1-tuple" means @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not *invalid* syntax. By adding a trailing comma, you wrap the field in a singleton tuple. So the type of `person.surname` is `tuple`.

For example if you write:

```
>>> a = 1,
>>> a
(1,)
>>> type(a)
<class 'tuple'>
```

A model can, besides the model fields contain all sorts of things: constants, subclasses, methods, etc.

One could do an exhaustive search in all the fields, etc. to check if a tuple wraps a model field, but that could take considerable time, it might result in evaluating lazy attributes, and it might even get stuck in an infinite loop.

It might however be something that can be added to [**`flake8-django`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/rocioar/flake8-django).

Comment: Ok, but what would be the use of that tuple and what would it look like in real. a tuple created with Django model field class

Comment: @Eternal: A tuple with one element: the Django model field you constructed (so here a `CharField` object).

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge @Willem. now I get it. However, I believe there should be some mechanism like you can not randomly enter anything between fields or something, I don't know maybe this sounds crazy. But some kind of restrictions?

Comment: @Eternal: well, it could be a valuable extension to `flake8-django`, which is a bit the `lint` of `Python/Django`. But it might require some extra work, so probably not yet done.

Comment: Are you the man behind this flake8-django? I would love to contribute if you/they ever decide to do something like that.

Comment: @Eternal: no, but you can definitely fork it and make a PR. The last one was approved in may, so the project is likely still "alive".